# MySQL error in phpmyadmin, when clicked on column to change

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I got this below error when clicked on column(s) to change. What is the reason for this error ?  I know that by doing this : `$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'never';` in `config.inc.php` will solve this issue but it just stops popping up the error message...

> Notice in .\libraries\tbl_columns_definition_form.inc.php#55 
>   Undefined variable: server
>
> Backtrace  .\libraries\structure.lib.php#2452:
>   include(.\libraries\tbl_columns_definition_form.inc.php)
>   .\tbl_structure.php#45: PMA_displayHtmlForColumnChange( string 'lr',
>   string 'users', NULL, string 'tbl_str

Comment: That is not an error.It clearly states it is a "Notice". Reason behind it is bad programming: a variable is referenced ($server) that is not defined (yet). You can change the error reporting of your php module in the configuration if you want to, to drop such notices. Or you fix the code. Maybe you even want to contribute your fix to the application. It certainly is more than welcome!

Comment: What is your phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: That version is a bit outdated now; you might look in to upgrading it. About your problem, though, try clearing your browser cache and removing the phpMyAdmin cookies (which start with `pma`) then trying again. At first look, it appears to be a browser caching issue.